# How to monkeypatch with a mock and set a return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I am attempting to test a function that calls `subprocess.run`. I would like to:

1. Check that `subprocess.run` is called with the expected arguments
2. Make the exit code zero

With the following code:

```
import subprocess
from unittest import mock

def test_foo(monkeypatch):
    m = mock.Mock(spec=['run'], **{
        'run.return_value.returncode': 0,
    })
    monkeypatch.setattr(subprocess, 'run', m)
    assert subprocess.run is m
    assert subprocess.run(['ls']).returncode == m.run(['ls']).returncode
```

Running `pytest` shows:

```
        assert subprocess.run is m
>       assert subprocess.run(['ls']).returncode == m.run(['ls']).returncode
E       AssertionError: assert <Mock name='mock().returncode' id='140293943645408'> == 0
E        +  where <Mock name='mock().returncode' id='140293943645408'> = <Mock name='mock()' id='140293943645352'>.returncode
E        +    where <Mock name='mock()' id='140293943645352'> = <Mock id='140293943644792'>(['ls'])
E        +      where <Mock id='140293943644792'> = subprocess.run
E        +  and   0 = <Mock name='mock.run()' id='140293943645184'>.returncode
E        +    where <Mock name='mock.run()' id='140293943645184'> = <Mock name='mock.run' id='140293943645128'>(['ls'])
E        +      where <Mock name='mock.run' id='140293943645128'> = <Mock id='140293943644792'>.run
```

The first assertion shows that `m` and `subprocess.run` are the same mock, yet the former has a `returncode` of `0` while the latter's `returncode` is another mock. Why is this?

Comment: Pretty sure the 3rd argument is a callable to monkey patch the original `'run'` with. So you're essentially saying, whenever I call `subprocess.run`, call `m` instead.  This happens to work because `mock.Mock` will let you do that. `subprocess.run is m` is true because they're the same function pointer. When you _call_ `subprocess.run` though, it returns the return value of `m()` which happens to be `mock()`.

Comment: Monkey patching might not be the right approach here. I'd highly recommend looking into using something like `mock.patch('subprocess.run')`. From there you can track the call counts and mock the return values as well.